# Is there a way to show the dependency graph of a Go package?

Tags: go, dependency-management

For example, given a package `A` that depends on package `B` and package `C`, where package `C` also depends on package `D` - is there a way to output this information? (Using a vendoring tool or otherwise)

The `vendor.yaml` output by `govend` doesn't include transitive dependency information - neither does the `Gopkg.toml` file 
output by `dep`, from what I can see. The `go.mod` file produced by Golang 1.11's mod and does annotate some dependencies as `// indirect` - but it does not annotate dependencies with any information about which dependency they were pulled in via.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want, `go mod graph` or `go mod why` (see `go mod help graph` and `go mod help why`) may be of use. The former can be piped through [`digraph`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/digraph) to answer some more specific questions about the graph. It would also be fairly easy to filter the `go mod graph` output into a form that could be piped into [`dot`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) to produce an image.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you try https://github.com/KyleBanks/depth?
It does provide a decent dependency tree at first look I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays the best way to figure dependency graph is to use `go mod graph`.

Here is the usage explanation from Go 1.21 (from `go help mod graph`):

```
usage: go mod graph [-go=version] [-x]

Graph prints the module requirement graph (with replacements applied)
in text form. Each line in the output has two space-separated fields: a module
and one of its requirements. Each module is identified as a string of the form
path@version, except for the main module, which has no @version suffix.

The -go flag causes graph to report the module graph as loaded by the
given Go version, instead of the version indicated by the 'go' directive
in the go.mod file.

The -x flag causes graph to print the commands graph executes.

See https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-graph for more about 'go mod graph'.
```

Here is the example output:

```
example.com/main example.com/a@v1.1.0
example.com/main example.com/b@v1.2.0
example.com/a@v1.1.0 example.com/b@v1.1.1
example.com/a@v1.1.0 example.com/c@v1.3.0
example.com/b@v1.1.0 example.com/c@v1.1.0
example.com/b@v1.2.0 example.com/c@v1.2.0
```